# Pondering of the fundamentals of graphing functions

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I was doing my calculus homework when I realized I didn't fully understand how graphing functions works. My questions is: is $f(x)$ a curve or is $f$ a curve? My thinking is that $f(x)$ is a specific but unknown ordinate (not coordinate) because the input x (or abscissa) is a specific but unknown value. That is why we name the vertical axis on a coordinate plane $f(x)$; we are plotting infinitely many f(x)s along with their corresponding x's to generate the curve f. My second question is that if I have a line segment of the curve $y=3$, I know it is made up of infinitely many points. Now if I cut off a line segment that is bigger than my first line segment, this new line segment is still made up of infinitely many points. But because the line segment is longer than before, do we have a case of one infinity being greater than the other?

Comment: The answer to your first question is correct. We graph $f$ and not $f \left( x \right)$. $f \left( x \right)$ gives the value of $f$ at a particular point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (or whatever the domain is, for that matter). For the second question, you should look up upon the cardinalities of (infinite) sets. You will understand that even if the second line segment is "longer" than the first one, it has as many points as the first one has.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Thank you

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Wait what if we have $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$? The function is f and if the curve is f then $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ should be the same curve. But they aren't.

Comment: Notice that neither $f \left( x \right)$ nor $f \left( -x \right)$ are curves. They are real numbers. In particular, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f \left( x \right)$ gives the value of $f$ at $x$ and $f \left( - x \right)$ gives the value of $f$ at $-x$ (which is in general, a different real number).

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh so $f$ is still the curve in each of the two situations? But each curve is different looking.

Comment: That is because by making $x$, $-x$, you are changing the "way" you look at the curve.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh could you elaborate more on these different ways of looking at the curve. I don't get it.